# Post commit hook for the svn update

Tags: svn, sudo

I have one repository and one working copy of it.

In the post-commit hook of repository I have written a command to execute one file which run the command of SVN update.

My repository is in the `/var/www/svnrepos/help/`

My working copy is in `/var/www/autopostcommit/help/`

Post-commit file is in the `/var/www/svnrepos/help/hooks/`

In the post-commit I have written following command

```
    sudo /usr/local/bin/svn-post-commit-update 1>&2
```

In the `svn-post-commit-update` file which is in /usr/local/bin I have written following command.

```
    cd /var/www/autopostcommit/help/
    svn update --non-interactive --trust-server-cert \
               --username satish@108.166.92.199 --password mypassword
```

I have also tried other version of command for the update like without password and all.

SVN commit gives me following error

```
   Error: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

You have configured `sudo` to ask for a password, which it cannot do in a the post-commit hook. Fix seems simple: Reconfigure `sudo` so it will not ask for a password in your case.

Cautious people don't want to run the post-commit hook as `root` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find some other way to execute your script as the correct user. Maybe making the script setuid is an option for you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Then you can remove the sudo.

Comment: Setuid is ignored on shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The real question: What are you trying to do?

When you execute a post-commit hook, the user who is doing the commit has to wait around until it's finished. If you're trying to update a remote working directory, your user is going to get very upset because each time they do a commit, it's going to take 10 to 20 seconds of thumb twiddling before hey get their computer back.

Some things are better not to do as a hook. Instead, use a crontab entry that simply checks the repository every minute for an update, and if there is an update, does whatever it needs to do.

I take it you're updating a webpage. My I make a slight suggestion: Don't use `svn update`. Instead use `svn export` which will get rid of all the `.svn` files (which I guess with version 1.7 isn't all that bad anymore). What I recommend doing is a two directory strategy:

You don't update your `/var/www/autopostcommit/help/` directly. Instead you do a `svn update` to another directory, then after the update is complete, move the `/var/www/autopostcommit/help` elsewhere, and move the directory you've exported to `/var/www/autopostcommit/help/`. This way, your `/var/www/autopostcommit/help` directory isn't in a state that's halfway between two revisions.